# Change strike-through in selected text in a textView

Tags: android, strikethrough

I was trying to strike a string in a textView when i select it ,then when i select it a second time it will be unstroken ,this is working for me but the problem is when i select this textView a third time it won't be stroken ,so can any one help me plz , this is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView txt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

        strike();

}


public void strike() {

    txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            txt.setPaintFlags(txt.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            //to remove strike
            txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    txt.setPaintFlags(0);


                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: I suggest setting a break point in strike() and see if it's executing the code the way you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that youre overriding the onClickListener after first click, so the listener would only clear the paint flags after the first click.

```
txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(txt.getPaintFlags() == 257){
            txt.setPaintFlags(txt.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG); 
        } else if(txt.getPaintFlags() == 273){ 
            txt.setPaintFlags(257); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thats because i dont know what return txt.getPaintFlags, check it on debug mode and discover what condition tells you the text has no paint flags :P

Comment: DO you got any problems @honeyyy

Comment: I gotta go, im not sure but it could be better to check if the text has the paint flag of strike instead of checking its emptyness. Im almost sure the problem relies on the if condition, ill check it on my own later.

Comment: Sorry for not checking this out before, code already edited :)